# Service Worker PostMessage Error

Tags: javascript, worker

I have the following:

```
//main.js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('worker.js').then(function(worker){
//      firebase.messaging().useServiceWorker(worker);
    navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage([MESSAGE HERE]);
    });
}
```

And in worker.js:

```
self.onmessage=function(e){
    console.log(e.data);
}
```

But in main.js, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null

Why is this happening?

Comment: check worker.active.postMessage

Comment: worker.active.postMessage worked!

Comment: Nice to hear, have a luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are going into a new function with the line

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('worker.js').then(function(worker){
```

and passing in your service worker as 'worker'

you should be able to replace

```
    navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage([MESSAGE HERE]);
```

with

```
 worker.active.postMessage('your message');
```

Comment: No such luck.
 navigator.serviceWorker.register('worker.js').then(function(worker){
  worker.postMessage(uid);
 });

Comment: Returns: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: worker.postMessage is not a function

Comment: Change worker. postMessage to worker.active.postMessage in the answer, and I'll accept it!