# postMessage from navigator in componentDidMount returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, prefetch

Im trying to implement some prefetching via a service worker that would be triggered when a React component mounts and has the data necessary for the worker to reach out to the API and return/cache the next set of queries a user might execute.

e.g. A user is on a page with a collection of products and I want to go out and prefetch the data for x amount of product pages.

Here is the current error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of undefined

```
componentDidMount() {
        const { products } = this.props.data;
        let partNumbersArr = [];
        // pull out partNumbers for PDP prefetch, limit to 6 [not using .map bc cannot break and in prod upto arrays of 120]
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            partNumbersArr.push(products[i].partNumber);
        }
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            const { serviceWorker } = navigator;

            serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
                .then((worker) => {
                    console.log('sw: registration', worker)
                    worker.controller.postMessage({partNumbersArr})
                })
            }
        }
```

In this example my code reaches the sw: registration console.log, but it is returning a worker instance without the postMessage available.

[image: worker instance console logged]

Part of my service-worker.js (I can post the whole thing but its created via webpack config so its multiple files)

```
// Prefetch
    self.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        console.log('sw: sw message event', event);
   });
```

Is my approach in the React component incorrect? How can I further debug the service worker and understand why the controller is not returning the expected method. Any advice helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, write the entire post and instantly figure it out - StackOverFlow magic.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            const { serviceWorker } = navigator;

            serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
                .then((worker) => {
                    console.log('sw: registration', worker)
                    worker.active.postMessage({partNumbersArr})
                })
            }
        }
```

What changed was worker.controller.postMessage to worker.active.postMessage

[image]

Now we are in business.

OG Post that pointed out my error

[Service Worker PostMessage Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51291483/service-worker-postmessage-error)